# Proving a change of variables is a variable over a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I was reading through some solutions to some problems in Lang [here](http://math.umn.edu/~phamx352/docs/Alg1Hw5.pdf/), and I was confused by some of the terminology. In particular, on page 25 of the document it says that "Now we show that Y is variable over A", $A$ being an integral domain and $Y=aX+b$, $a$ a unit. Does it make sense to need to prove this? Their meaning, it seems, is that if we have a polynomial over $A$, then $g(Y)=0 \rightarrow g = 0$. I've never heard of needing to show this before.

Comment: The condition about $g(Y)=0$ seems to be saying that $Y$ is transcendental over $A$ which does make sense to talk about and is probably what they mean. The term variable seems like an outdated version for transcendental but I am not sure.